# Starting the Ubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation

Original question:  I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.4-desktop-amd64 onto a USB memory card.  Clicking this ISO file reveals a number of folders and subfolders, but nowhere in any of these is a setup file or information on how to do the installation.  I am tempted by the single file in the folder INSTALL, but cautious. Is this how the installation is started?  If so, will I be queried as to the drive I want to boot from?

Reply to Ans 1:  Thanks Guillermo.  That was likely the right answer, but something went wrong in the execution. When I clicked "create" I got an immediate response that an error had occurred, and that my USB device (memory card) would not be bootable.  But the creation continued, and I ended up with a "WUBI" application on the card. With trepidation I double clicked it.  I bailed out when the operating system asked if I wanted this application to make changes to my computer.  I don't know where this was going, but obviously not to  a bootable USB device.  The error meant what it said.  I don't know what caused the error, or what my next step should be.

Comment: You must set boot priority in the BIOS/UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to install ubuntu from a USB you need to make it bootable not just copying the iso file.

The process for making a live ubuntu USB can be found here ( Assuming you are on Windows system) :

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows